# Output to CSV takes Forever for millions of records - PHP - Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have written the following PHP code which works great if there are less number of records to compare, If the database has 2,000,000 records to compare (One Single Table) it doesnt download the CSV file and takes forever. NOt sure if my query is wrong or some problem in PHP, the file should start downloading immediately after comparison.

**Mysql process list shows the following**

[image]

**PHP Code**

```
    $ids="1,23,24";
        header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Output.csv');

        // create a file pointer connected to the output stream
        $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');   
        //output the column headings
        fputcsv($output, array('code', 'Min', 'IMin','ICare','IRCare'));

             $sql1 = 'select d.code, d1.inter_Rate, d2.intra_rate, d1.carrier as c1, d2.carrier as c2
                from S_DATA d
                left join S_DATA d1 ON d1.code = d.code 
                and d1.inter_Rate = (select min(s1.inter_Rate) from S_DATA s1 where s1.code = d1.code)
                left join S_DATA d2 ON d2.code = d.code 
                and d2.intra_rate = (select min(s2.intra_rate) from S_DATA s2 where s2.code = d2.code)
                where d.file_log in ('.$ids.')
                group by d.code';

              $rp =  mysqli_query($con,$sql1,MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);   
               $total = mysqli_num_rows($rp);
                    if($total != 0) {
                                 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rp))
                                    {
                                    fputcsv($output, $row);
                                    }
                                 }  
         mysqli_free_result($rp);
         exit;
     ?>
```

S_DATA Data structure

[image]

Indexes below

[image]

**Explain below**

[image]

Comment: So what indexes do you have on your tables? Have you done an EXPLAIN on the query to show how the database is executing the query?

Comment: did you test how long does it take for your query to execute? if that's not the bottleneck, you could try writing in batches...

Comment: @MarkBaker I updated the question with the screen with indexes

Comment: @hummingBird takes almost  Showing rows 0 - 24 (155673 total, Query took 0.0369 seconds.)

Answer (score 2):

There are, at least, a couple of things that can cause the slow response.

1. The indices, or lack thereof, used in the table. Which affects the time it takes to actually execute the query.
2. The fact that you're writing each individual line to the disk.

The first one we need more information to help you with, as someone just commented on. Use `EXPLAIN` in front of your select query, and add it to your question. Since the query only took a few miliseconds when you ran it directly, then this hints towards the PHP code to be the actual bottle-neck. It keeps on sending data for as long as the PHP code hasn't finished fetching.

The second part is easier to fix immediately. Namely by using a temporary variable, adding to it instead of writing to disk for each iteration. However, to avoid using too much RAM on your server, you need to also check the size of said variable. If it hits a limit specified by you (2 MB, for example), then you can write it to disk and empty the variable.

Something like this:

```
$tmp = '';
while ($data = $res->get ()) {
    // Note that you need to write the format_csv () function yourself.
    $tmp .= format_csv ($data);

    // If the size is above an arbitrary, but sensible, limit.
    if (strlen ($tmp) >= 2000000) {
        // The CSV is pre-formatted, thus file_put_contents ()
        file_put_contents ($file, $tmp);
        $tmp = '';
    }
}
```

Note that `fputcsv()` only deals with one line at a time, so you'll need to write the a wrapper function that uses an alternative stream (or some other trick). So that you can return the result from `fputscsv()` as a string, or (not really recommended) write your own CSV-generation code.

You really should put your code through a profiler first though, to find out which parts of the code are the actual bottlenecks.

Comment: Thanks, updated my answer with more specific information as well.

Answer (score 1):

@ChristianF raised a good point, it might simply be the query that is slow.

But I think what's slowing you down is a quirk in PHP's mysqli, which by default waits for the entire query to complete, and is fully downloaded to PHP's memory, before returning from the mysqli_query() function.

For very large queries, that's obviously problematic. You're already streaming the results of the query to the output, that's a good thing, but your mysql driver isn't doing that.

If you look at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

There's the MYSQLI_USE_RESULT option, which allows you to use result rows as they come into PHP from Mysql. There's a major caveat here, you have to use mysqli_free_result() before starting another query, or you'll get errors. mysqli_num_rows() also will not work with a streaming result, since the total number of rows may be unknown at the beginning of the stream.

```
$rp =  mysqli_query($con, $sql1, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);  
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rp)) {
    fputcsv($output, $row);
  }
}
mysqli_free_result($rp);
```

Comment: I user MYSQLI_USE_RESULT but it didnt not make any difference in the result, I have updated the question

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you look at two php.ini parameters:

- memory_limit - sets how much memory is allocated to your scripts
- max_execution_time - sets how long a script has to run before it's killed

By increasing either (or both), your php script should run.

Comment: @memory_limit 128M, max_execution_time 30

Comment: Problem isn't that the script doesn't run, but that the length of time it takes is  inordinate for the task it should accomplish. In other words, the OP wants it to go faster. Your answer doesn't do this.